# Fill a listview from a combobox

Tags: c#, listview, combobox

I am having some trouble with my code and didn't get any result from the resources found,so below is my example when I select from the combobox a value the event `SelectionChangeCommitted` is fired up and should fill my listview control with the date,from the database related to my SELECT,but I am getting an error and I don't know how to handle it,I'd appreciate it if someone can help me.

In the constructor i have this code:

```
this.medic.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(medic_SelectionChangeCommitted);

private void medic_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter alegsectie = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT C.denumire,OC.Data,OC.ora_inc,OC.ora_sf FROM cabinete AS C INNER JOIN orar_clinica AS OC ON c.id_cabinet = OC.id_cabinet INNER JOIN medici AS M ON OC.id_medic = M.id_medic and M.nume =" + medic.SelectedValue, conn);

    DataSet listView1 = new DataSet();
    alegsectie.Fill(listView1);
```

ERROR:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the varchar
>   value 'pop' to data type int.

'pop' is the selectedvalue in combobox.

Comment: What is the type of `M.nume` column? And use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation. This makes your query open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: M.nume is a varchar(30),i check the query in the sql server and it correctly.

Comment: Yes,it a winform,and base on my selection in the combobox should fill my listview from a database.

Comment: the ListView control in WinForms is not a bound control.  Storing data in a Dataset *called* `listView1` wont do anything.  You'll have to manually add Items and SubItems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If M.nume is of type varchar you will need the value to be wrapped in single quotes in order for the sql statement to be valid:

```
SqlDataAdapter alegsectie = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT C.denumire,OC.Data,OC.ora_inc,OC.ora_sf FROM cabinete AS C INNER JOIN orar_clinica AS OC ON c.id_cabinet = OC.id_cabinet INNER JOIN medici AS M ON OC.id_medic = M.id_medic and M.nume ='" + medic.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
```

Note however that this approach to running queries is vulnerable to [Sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Maybe think about using [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to run your queries.

Hope that helps

Comment: good point about sql injection vulnaribility... plus 1 for that!